# Delay triggerring of `after_action` in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In our Rails 4.2 app, the `main_app` index action renders main menu and fires up a `after_action` to do something after rendering:

```
  class UserMenus < ApplicationController
    after_action :do_something
    def index
      ........
      render 'user_menus/index'
    end
  end
```

In `user_menus.index view`, there are links which link to a few engines' (modules) index page. Here is one of them:

```
   link_to 'Payment Request', payment_requestx.reqeusts_path
```

Here `payment_requestx` is the engine name.

The order of `Rails` execution of `render "user_menus/index"` is to first render user menus index view => fire up `after_action do_something` => load all engine models such as `request` on index page.

We need to have the `after_action do_something` fired `AFTER` models on `user menu index view` have all been loaded (now `after_action do_something` triggers before models loading). Is there a way to do that?

Comment: If the some action has anything to do with models extend initializer of model class. Controller should only initialize objects and pass them to view. I can not see any excuses to that.